# Differences in precision of randomly generated numbers between Matlab and Python

Tags: python, matlab, python-2.7, math

I am translating a Matlab algorithm in Python. To debug it, I had to rewrite several rand-related functions in order to synchronize the seeds between the two languages. I still had convergence differences between the two codes despite the (apparently) same numbers being randomly generated. I traced back the error to my rewritten randn() function, which I need to return 2 numbers from the standard normal distribution. Below are the Matlab, and Python version of this randn() function rewritten with the Box-Müller method:

Matlab:

```
function output = newRandn(input)

output=zeros(input,1);

for i = 1:input
    output(i) = sqrt(-2*log(rand())) * cos(2*pi*rand());
end
```

Python:

```
def newRandn(size):
    x = np.arange(0.0, size)
    for i in xrange(0,size,1):
        x[i] = math.sqrt(-2*math.log(numpy.random.rand())) * math.cos(2*math.pi*numpy.random.rand())
    return x
```

Both codes are synchronized with the same seed. Here, I am using

```
rng('default')
rng(3530723506)
```

and

```
numpy.random.seed(3530723506)
```

For Matlab and python, respectively.

Looking at the output of both functions from a simple for loop, I spot a difference (shown in bold), in this case,  at a far decimal in the first number at the 21th iteration:

Matlab:

- 1.10773989463900**091045900353492470458149909973144531**
  0.16119915478508828332593338927836157381534576416016

Python:

- 1.10773989463900**113250360845995601266622543334960938**
  0.16119915478508828332593338927836157381534576416016

Code used:

```
rng('default')
rng(3530723506)

for i = 1:50
    temp = newRandn(2);
    fprintf('%d\n     %.50f\n     %.50f\n', i, temp(1), temp(2))
end
```

and in Python:

```
import numpy
import math
numpy.random.seed(3530723506)
for i in xrange(1, 26, 1):
        temp = newRandn(2);
        print i
        print "     %.50f"%temp[0]
        print "     %.50f"%temp[1]
```

Further iterations are mostly correct, but some numbers also contain precision errors such as this one. I cannot understand why some numbers are correct (at least up to the precision displayed), and others not.
I tried playing with the precision of pi, (e.g. creating a variable mypi = 3.14), but to no avail. In some cases my algorithm would converge similarly between the two versions using pi = 3.14, but other seeds would then fail instead.
Any help as to understand where these precision errors come from and how to overcome them would be greatly appreciated !

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried printing out all the intermediate results? That might help pinpoint exactly which operation introduces the divergence. I would guess that it's one of the operations that is only expected to be accurate within one ULP, such as log.

Comment: 64 bit IEEE floating point numbers only have 17 digits of precision.  It's not an error.

Comment: @duffymo Actually, these values differ from one `eps` exactly (their hex representation is respectively `3ff1b94d77bf2f15` and `3ff1b94d77bf2f16`), which means that there is an actual difference and it's not just the `fprintf` implementation or something that goes wrong (although agreed, the digits after the 17th can be ignored)... @Syl_T I would indeed print out the intermediary results to see which operation goes wrong... You can assume that it's not the random generator, since subsequent numbers are correct again... Must be one of the transformations..

Comment: My guess is that one of the library functions (log, cos, sqrt) is returning a slightly different result for some argument. One way to detect any differences outside of newRandn is to generate a long sequence of numbers in Matlab and then just read them into Python (i.e., replace the body of newRandn with some code to return the next 2 numbers from the list).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html 
Since Matlab is not implemented in Python, you can safely conclude this not being an error.